# Quantum Computing

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer, nanoscience

Could quantum computing ultimately harness the Higgs boson interactions to artificially provide mass (energy) to particles in order to manipulate them?

Comment: To reopen this question, please explain in more detail what you think the link between quantum computing and the higgs field is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quantum computing as we understand now doesn't change fundamental interactions (coupling constants) between particles, Higgs or otherwise. Quantum computing merely utilizes the superposition of multiple states of quantum bits to perform operations in one go, that would require many separate operations to classical bits.